# How to stop f2c from printing names of each subroutine and function

Tags: f2c

Our build scripts run f2c over several thousand subroutines and functions, so our build output consists of large amounts of output like:

```
   a102:
   a200:
   a210:
   acalc:
   actdis:
   addvec:
   adhydr:
   alsun:
```

We are running f2c version 20100827.

The f2c command line used is:

```
f2c -Nx5000 -Nn3200 -NL1500 -a -R -ec -doutput
```

I've found the [f2c man page](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/f2c.1) and can't see any relevant options there.

Without editing the f2c source code, is there some other way, e.g. some undocumented feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to delete the function names is to pipe the output of f2c through grep:

```
$F2C_EXE $f2c_options      output/$file.f 2>&1 | grep -v '^   [a-zA-Z]'
```

This works because the function and subroutine names are prefixed with three spaces, and the `-v` grep option tells grep to print all lines *except* the matching ones.

The `2>&1` is required because f2c seems to write all its output to stderr, not stdout.